# Choicelist in form based on request

Tags: symfony

I build a form type with a choice list / entity. I will load only specified entities in this choice field, this is dependent on a parameter in request.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('children', 'entity', array(
                        'class' => 'AppMyBundle:Items',
                        'choices' => array(), // <------ This i fill dynamic, based on request parameter
                        'label' => '',
                        'translation_domain' => 'messages',
                        'multiple' => true,
                        'expanded' => false,
                        'attr' => array('class' => 'childrens'))
                );
    }
```

Can i access the request in form type? Or how can i handle this issue?

**Update**

I have following entities. A questionnaire which have many sections and sections which have many questions.

- Questionnaire to Sections: OneToMany
- Sections to Question: OneToMany

A question entity have a one to many self reflection.

Question:

```
/**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Question", mappedBy="parent")
     **/
    private $children;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Question", inversedBy="children")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $parent;
```

If a user click to edit a questionnaire, i will list all questions in this questionnaire. In first step i get all sections and after that i collect all questions for this sections and display a list view for a specified questionnaire.

Know if a user click to edit a question for a specified questionnaire, i will only show child elements which is in this specified questionnaire.

Thats my issue :)

Comment: Yes, you could access the `Request` object inside the `buildForm` method using form's options or custom object properties. However this doesn't sound like the very best idea - could you write more about your problem?

Comment: @crozin hi, thank you for your support. i try to describe my issue with some details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inject the `Request` in the `$options` of 
`public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)`,

and then access it through: `$request = $options['req']`;

Inject it as follow:

```
$taskForm = $this->createForm(new TaskType(), $task, array(
   'req' => $this->getRequest(),
));
```

And add it requirements in :

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver
        ->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\Task',
        ))
        ->setRequired(array('req'))
        ->setAllowedTypes('req', 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request')

    // ...
}
```

Comment: if i try to inject options like request $this->createForm($this->get('form.type.question'), $question, array('req' => $request))  i get the error message "The option "req" does not exist. Known options are: "action", "allow_extra_fields"..... Or must i inject this in service.yml for my form service?